# Springboot Application started successfully but the required table is not created in MySql Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring framework. I am trying to create a CRUD application. After running the Spring application, the application starting successfully but database is not getting updated. My database name is Emp. When the springboot application started successfully I refreshed the database but no table named "employees" is added there.

**My project structure is as follows:**

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLLQG.png)

**There is no compilation error as of now.**

**Following is the generated console after running the application-**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)

2023-09-29T18:52:42.309+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] com.cts.Employee.EmployeeApplication     : Starting EmployeeApplication using Java 17.0.8 with PID 1908 (C:\Users\Gals\eclipse-workspace\Employee\target\classes started by Gals in C:\Users\Gals\eclipse-workspace\Employee)
2023-09-29T18:52:42.318+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] com.cts.Employee.EmployeeApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-29T18:52:44.171+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-09-29T18:52:44.245+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 47 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-09-29T18:52:45.852+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-09-29T18:52:45.880+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-09-29T18:52:45.880+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.13]
2023-09-29T18:52:46.137+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-09-29T18:52:46.140+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3654 ms
2023-09-29T18:52:46.617+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-09-29T18:52:46.756+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.9.Final
2023-09-29T18:52:46.762+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-09-29T18:52:47.100+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-29T18:52:47.431+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-09-29T18:52:47.468+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-09-29T18:52:47.864+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@6842c101
2023-09-29T18:52:47.868+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-09-29T18:52:49.346+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-09-29T18:52:51.157+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-09-29T18:52:51.218+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-09-29T18:52:51.389+05:30  WARN 1908 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-09-29T18:52:53.771+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-09-29T18:52:53.797+05:30  INFO 1908 --- [           main] com.cts.Employee.EmployeeApplication     : Started EmployeeApplication in 12.466 seconds (process running for 13.365)
```

**Following is the Application.properties file present in src/main/resources -**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=''

# Hibernate properties
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
# create, create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

** Following is the Pom.xml-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.cts</groupId>
    <artifactId>Employee</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Employeemanagement</name>
    <description>Employee Management using Spring boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Following is my employee model - **

```
package com.cts.Employee.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class EmployeeModel {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;
}
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

Tried making changes in application.properties file.

Used
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

instead of
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

but that didn't help.

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect - this dialect is giving errors in the code. So I had to use spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: Remove `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`, fix compilation errors by using `jakarta.persistence` imports.

Comment: Go to start.spring.io and use the dependencies and defaults from there.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that SpringBoot does not discover your Entity class?
If you have a certain project structure where the main application class is in another path, you might need to add `scanBasePackages` property:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.cts.Employee")
public class EmployeeApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeApplication.class, args)
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work. I have added the project structure to the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` in the Hibernate properties.

Comment: Tried. But not working